# Multilevel Drop-down not able to implement using bootstrap and on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none
}


.navbar-nav:hover .secondDropdown{
  display:block;
}


.navbar-nav .secondDropdown{
  display:none;
}


.navbarDropdown2{
  display:none;
}


.dropdown-toggle:hover .navbarDropdown2 {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-item:hover ul{
     display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Apparel </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu secondDropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Girls</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
            <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a href="/Apparel/Girls/Shoes/10015">Shoes</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Boys</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
            <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a href="/Apparel/Boys/Pants/10019">Pants</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Women</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
            <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a href="/Apparel/Women/Dresses/10001">Dresses</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Men</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
            <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a href="/Apparel/Men/Jackets/10009">Jackets</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Electronics </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu secondDropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Accessories</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2"></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Grocery </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu secondDropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dairy</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2"></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Health </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu secondDropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Medicine</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2"></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Home &amp; Furnishing </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu secondDropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Bath Accessories</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2"></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Newsletters &amp; Magazines </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu secondDropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Magazines</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2"></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hello, I'm new to css and bootstrap. I'm trying to implement a multilevel dropdown using css and bootstrap 4. But, I'm finding a particular error. Whenever I click on the items in the list, all opens at the same time. I have shared my code in the FIDDLe. I don't know where I'm getting it wrong. I have tried with display: block and display:none, but it's not working.

Can somebody please guide me on this. I would be grateful if someone could provide me an insight into this.Thanks

Comment: try using the immediate child selector ` > ` instead of the space (which has a name but I refer to it as a "general child")

Comment: Also I just noticed that it seems like all of your dropdown toggles all point to `navbarDropdown2` which is probably not what you wanted. IDS are meant to be unique.

Comment: Is there a way to resolve this...I'm getting very much confused

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were looking for. The problem, if this is what you were looking for, was that you were having the hover called on the `.navbar-nav` element, which meant that all `secondDropdown` classes were being modified by this since they are all descendants of the navbar. Changing `.navbar-nav:hover` to `.dropdown:hover` was the solution

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none
}

.dropdown:hover .secondDropdown {
  display: block;
}

.navbar-nav .secondDropdown {
  display: none;
}

.navbarDropdown2 {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-toggle:hover>.navbarDropdown2 {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-item:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Apparel </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu secondDropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Girls</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
            <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a href="/Apparel/Girls/Shoes/10015">Shoes</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Boys</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
            <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a href="/Apparel/Boys/Pants/10019">Pants</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Women</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
            <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a href="/Apparel/Women/Dresses/10001">Dresses</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Men</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
            <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a href="/Apparel/Men/Jackets/10009">Jackets</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Electronics </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu secondDropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Accessories</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2"></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Grocery </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu secondDropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dairy</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2"></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Health </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu secondDropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Medicine</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2"></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Home &amp; Furnishing </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu secondDropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Bath Accessories</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2"></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Newsletters &amp; Magazines </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu secondDropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Magazines</a>
          <ul class="" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2"></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```